# Lowering front frame away from the handlebars on 2007 yamaha R6S

Tags: motorcycle, yamaha, handlebars

I recently bought a 2007 R6S I was wondering if there is a way to lower the front frame so there is a greater separation between the handlebars and the plastic. When I go for a very tight turn the handlebar will hit the plastic and I can't fit my hand on it.
Thank you

Comment: change the bars or change the angle of the bar..

Comment: @solar-mike how would I go about doing that?

Comment: The handlebar tilt may be adjustable @Mavese, in which case you could rotate it forward for more clearance.